# ORA-00918:column ambiguously defined on inner join

Tags: oracle

Keep getting an error when trying to create a view with an inner join:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW lab3view3
AS
SELECT 
       f.firstname,
       f.lastname,
       s.firstname,
       s.lastname,
       c.coursename, 
       sec.days, 
       TO_CHAR (sec.starttime, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS startdate,
       TO_CHAR(sec.starttime, 'HH:MI AM    ') AS starttime,
       TO_CHAR(sec.endtime, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS enddate, 
       TO_CHAR(sec.endtime, 'HH:MI AM    ') AS endtime,
       sec.sectionid,
       l.building, 
       l.room,
       g.grade
FROM  section sec
        INNER JOIN grade g
                    ON g.sectionid = sec.sectionid
        INNER JOIN course c
                    ON c.courseid = sec.courseid
        INNER JOIN location l
                    ON l.locationid = sec.locationid
        INNER JOIN student s
                    ON s.studentid = g.studentid
        INNER JOIN instructor i
                    ON i.sectionid = sec.sectionid
        INNER JOIN faculty f
                    ON f.facultyid = i.facultyid
        INNER JOIN section sec
                    ON sec.sectionid = g.sectionid;
```

Keep getting this error:

ERROR AT LINE 1;

ORA-00918:column ambiguously defined

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to also prefix the times in the `TO_CHAR` (`starttime` and `endtime`) call with the correct table. Also you are selecting `firstname` and `lastname` twice from different tables, <strike>the second one will be renamed to `firstname_1` then</strike>, they have to be renamed because you are creating a view, see @sstan's answer.

Comment: thank you for the input, I updated my data but I am still getting the "column ambiguously defined" error...

Comment: Have you found anything yet? Are those all tables or are some of the "things" you select from also views? Maybe one of those views has an error or has to be recompiled. If something becomes invalid for whatever reason the error messages can be very missleading in oracle.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't gotten anywhere yet. everything selected is from a table and ran my other views with no problems. I commented everything out leaving: 

SELECT sec.days 
FROM section sec 
 INNER JOIN section sec 
   ON sec.sectionid = g.sectionid

And now am getting an error that says "missing expression"

Comment: Got it figured out! I did not have any overlap in my sectionID between my registration table and instructor table. Once I updated that data it worked fine! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

@maraca's answer is correct. But once you fix the ambiguously defined column error, you will then get

> ORA-00957: duplicate column name

When creating a view, every selected column needs to have a unique name.  Make sure you alias the duplicate column names in the `select` clause accordingly.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW lab3view3
    AS
    SELECT faculty.firstname as faculty_firstname,
           faculty.lastname as faculty_lastname,
           student.firstname as student_firstname,
           student.lastname as student_lastname,
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I updated my data to follow your advice (updated above) but am still getting the same error

Comment: That's because you didn't apply @maraca's answer.  You need to fix `to_char(<table_name>.starttime, ...`, etc.. to qualify the column name with the table name.  We can only assume that `starttime` and `endtime` exists in more than one table, so you need to be more explicit about which one you want.

Comment: the to_char statements I used in previous views as-is with no errors...I used a select statement to format them earlier on. I edited my post again with more corrections to ensure no column names are alike but keep getting the "column ambiguously defined" error...

Comment: tbh, I don't see how you are still getting that error. If I were you, I would slowly reduce the query until I'm able to isolate the cause of the problem. If you want help, you'll have to post a minimal, but complete script that allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes, I can't see any reason as to why either, very frustrating! Will take your advice to see if I can find the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Got it figured out! I did not have any overlap in my sectionID between my registration table and instructor table. Once I updated that data it worked fine! Thanks for your help